# How can I write a non-greek name in a greek text?

Tags: beamer, languages, greek

I want to write a text in Greek and there are some non-greek names.

I used the following code:

```
\begin{frame}{Ιστορική αναδρομή}
Το 1926 ο $\textenglish{David Hilbert }$ ισχυρίζεται ότι κάθε υπολογίσιμη συνάρτηση είναι πρωταρχικά αναδρομική.  $ \\ \\ $ 
\end{frame}
```

I used the following package:

```
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...-Το 1926 ο \textenglish 
                                                  {David Hilbert } ισχυ�...
l.66 \end{frame}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

What have I done wrong?? What could I change??

Comment: First question, why math mode?

Comment: Do you mean why I use the $ $ ?? I tried it without them, and since it didn't work I tried it with them but it still doesn't work... @Johannes_B

Comment: `\foreignlanguage{english}{David Hilbert} `. And all this math is simply wrong.

Comment: When I write this instead of \textenglish{} I get exactly the same erroe as before, although I don't use \textenglish{} it says that "Το 1926 ο \textenglish 
                                                  {David Hilbert } ισχυ�...
l.66 \end{frame}" Why?? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: LaTeX doesn't invent commands. If is says there is a \textenglish, it is there. So check if you saved the file, changed the right file, changed all occurances of \textenglish, etc.

Comment: Or write `\newcommand*\textenglish{\foreignlanguage{english}}` and use `\textenglish{..}`.

Comment: I hadn't saved it correctly... Now it works!! Thanks!! :-) @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to convert you comment into an answer? Sounds like it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\foreignlanguage{english}{David Hilbert}`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, especially for abbreviations and other text in a Latin script in an unspecified language, you can use `\ensureascii`, e.g., `\ensureascii{SNCF}`.

Or use LuaLaTeX and a Unicode font that contains Latin and Greek letters.

For details, read the [babel-greek](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-greek) documentation.